# With default paperclip URL structure of 000/000/001 style, what happens when we hit 999/999/999?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Just wondering, we have deployed with the default configuration that splits the :id for the paperclip attachment across the 3 url fragments, e.g 000/000/028.

What we want to know is, what happens when it ticks over the 999/999/999 to 1000000000 records, does it simply add another url fragment, e.g 001/000/000/000 ?

Or, does something really bad happen?

Comment: why don't you try it?

Comment: because it's on a production system and it's not really convenient to upload over 1 billion images even in a test environment, and I would think that someone out there might actually know the answer (especially probably the original developer), I did ask this in the google group for paperclip but no one even answered there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you'll have a problem. My best efforts to track the source that generates this leads me to this method:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/282f1161e8cbdd314e06af51d7ad01feb8b5c196/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb#L162

Since the `id` is an Integer, it will be processed with:

`("%09d" % id).scan(/\d{3}/).join("/")`

My fiddling with pry show that the URL generated for the billionth item will be the same as for the hundred-millionth. Hmmm.

```
[1] pry(main)> id = 999_999_999
=> 999999999
[2] pry(main)> ("%09d" % id).scan(/\d{3}/).join("/")
=> "999/999/999"
[3] pry(main)> id = 1_000_000_000
=> 1000000000
[4] pry(main)> play -i 2      # (runs expression #2 again)
=> "100/000/000"
[5] pry(main)> id = 100_000_000
=> 100000000
[6] pry(main)> play -i 2
=> "100/000/000"
```

Since the default url is `:rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename`, if the style and filename for the 1,000,000,000th and 100,000,000th image are the same, then I imagine there would be a collision. It's possible there is logic somewhere in paperclip to check for this and circumvent it, however I didn't see any in my (admittedly cursory) journeys through the code.

Comment: +1 for the debugging effort.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the input, we actually came to the same conclusion ourselves, and have been through the code reasonably thoroughly as well, and as you corroborate our findings as well I'll mark this as the answer.  It would be great if the paperclip guys/girls could give us a definitive :)

Comment: If you're actually worried about this limit, it should be easy enough to use a forked version of paperclip that has a different implementation of this method. Presumably, if you have the resources to get to a billion uploads, you've got the resources to change ~10 lines in a gem :) Cheers!